# Why can't I pass a decorated function to scipy.integrate.ode?

Tags: python, scipy, decorator, wrapper, ode

When I pass a decorated function to scipy.integrate.ode, the wrapper function gets called, but *args is empty. Why is this happening?

This works:

```
y0, t0 = 1, 0

def dydt(t, y):
    return y*0.5

r = scipy.integrate.ode(dydt)
r.set_initial_value(y0)
r.integrate(10)
assert r.successful()
```

This doesn't:

```
y0, t0 = 1, 0

def dec_func(func):
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_func

@dec_func
def dydt(t, y):
    return y*0.5

r = scipy.integrate.ode(dydt)
r.set_initial_value(y0)
r.integrate(10)
assert r.successful()
```

It return this error: `TypeError: dydt() missing 2 required positional arguments: 't' and 'y'`

When I insert a line into the wrapper function to print the length of args, it comes back as 0.

EDIT:
This doesn't work either. Same result as main post

```
from functools import wraps

y0, t0 = 1, 0

def dec_func(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_func

@dec_func
def dydt(t, y):
    return y*0.5

r = scipy.integrate.ode(dydt)
r.set_initial_value(y0)
r.integrate(10)
assert r.successful()
```

Comment: Something's probably relying on signature inspection to determine what arguments to pass. Try [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: @user2357112 Same error, assuming I used functools right. See edit to post

Comment: What you probably want to achieve is the effect of
`func = lambda t,x: func_proto(t,x,**kwargs)`
The same effect can be achieved by using the args keyword in the integrator. You should use keywords in your example, for instance for the growth factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's still an open question exactly what is going on inside scipy. Here is the workaround I'm going with.

```
y0, t0 = 1, 0

def dec_func(func):
    def wrap_func(t, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(t, y, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_func

@dec_func
def dydt(t, y):
    return y*0.5

r = scipy.integrate.ode(dydt)
r.set_initial_value(y0)
r.integrate(10)
assert r.successful()
```

Comment: But what have you achieved here? There are no extra arguments here, the decorator effectively replaces the function with itself.

Comment: I simplified as much as I could while still showing the problem. My actual application has the wrapper modify the y vector on its way in and out of dydt.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are constructing the decorator -- in particular the inner function -- seems to mangle the function signature of `dydt`.  `scipy.integrate.ode` needs to be passed a callable f(t,y) with signature such that t is a scalar, `y.shape == (n,)` and `f` returns a scalar or list (taken from the scipy docs).  The result of decorating `dydt` the way you did does not seem to conform -- although the difference is somewhat lost on me.

doing it this way works:

```
def dec_func(func):
    def wrap_func(t, y):
        return func(t, y)
    return wrap_func

@dec_func
def dydt2(t, y):
    return y*0.5

r = scipy.integrate.ode(dydt2)
r.set_initial_value(y0)
r.integrate(10)
assert r.successful()
```

I did try a few things that I thought would allow you to keep the inner function generic (args, kwargs), but I never found anything that worked.

It's not that you can't pass a decorated function.  Unfortunately there seem to be some hidden requirements as to the way the function is decorated, though.